# Running "bundle install" gives "Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst" error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundle, bundler

I’m using Ubuntu.  I just upgraded my Ruby version, or at least I thought I did …

```
myuser@myproject:~/myproject$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
```

However when I try and run “bundle install,” I get some crazy errors, none of which I understand …

```
myuser@myproject:~/myproject$ bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem- wrappers-1.2.7, minitest-5.4.3, power_assert-0.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.0.8] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Ditto when I try and run a simple “bundle update” …

```
myuser@myproject:~/myproject$ bundle update
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem- wrappers-1.2.7, minitest-5.4.3, power_assert-0.2.2, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, test-unit-3.0.8] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

What do I need to do to get “bundle install” and “bundle update” working?

Comment: `gem install bundler` :)

Comment: Should it be juist "gem install" or "sudo gem install"?  I get teh error "You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 directory." when I run that command

Comment: Always try it without the `sudo` if you can. Looks like you may need to fix that error before proceeding - as I recall (from the dim, dark past when I first set up my Ubuntu box) there's something you need to `chmod` to make it work. I'd google for the error message.

Comment: Your system is confusing two different ruby installs, one system wide and one user only. 

Did you install ruby 2.2.2 with rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Follow @Taryn East's answer